# On a question migrated from another site, it is possible to make operations on a post without an associated account on the receiving site

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, convert-to-comment, convert-to-edit

I am referring to [Override comment.tpl.php file with theme](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32527/override-drupal-comment-tpl-php-file-with-theme). There was an answer that was more a comment, and I tried to convert it to a comment. I was not able, as I got an error saying, "Comment must have a valid owner."

I also noticed that the option to convert it in an edit was also accessible.

[image: screenshot]

Converting to a comment should not be possible, if the user account doesn't exist on the site. When I load the page, it is already know the post doesn't have a valid user.
For the same reason, converting the post in an edit should not be possible, as a valid user is different from a valid user.

Comment: For now, it's probably best just to delete it. If there's anything useful or important you could post it yourself. Also, if the user shows up and takes ownership of the account you could then undelete the answer and convert it to a comment. I know that doesn't solve the bug problem though ;)